# On what functions can an induced representation be implemented?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

DEFINITION

We start with a known representation $D(K)$ of a subgroup $K<G$, and construct a representation of $G$. The latter representation will be *induced* by the former.

The representation $D(K)$ is implemented with linear operators acting in a space ${\mathbb{W}}\,$:
 $$
 D:\quad K\to{\rm{GL}}({\mathbb{W}})~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
 $$
  The linear space ${\mathbb{W}}$ may be, e.g., that of all smooth functions.

The induced representation of $G$ will be acting on a subspace ${\mathbb{V}}\subset{\mathbb{W}}$ comprising the so-called *Mackey functions*, sometimes also referred to as *equivariant functions*. These are the functions satisfying the subsidiary condition
 $$
 {\mathbb{V}} = \{~
    \varphi \in {\mathbb{W}}
    \quad
    \mid
    \quad
    \text{$\varphi(gk) = D^{-1}(k)\varphi(g)~~,\quad$ for $\forall k \in K$, $g \in G~$}
    \}.\qquad\qquad(2)
 $$
 Denoted with $~D(K)\uparrow G~$ or $~$Ind$^G_KD~$, the induced representation is implemented by operators
 $$
 U:\quad G\to{\rm{GL}}({\mathbb{V}})~,\qquad~~
 U_g \varphi(x) = \varphi(g^{-1}x)\quad\mbox{for}\quad \forall g,\,x\in G\qquad\qquad (3)
 $$

MOTIVATION FOR THE ABOVE DEFINITION

Consider the quotient space $G/K$ and choose a representative $r(X)$ in each coset X, so the coset could be written as $X=r(X)K$. Apply our definition to a representative:
 $$
 U_g\varphi(r(X)) = \varphi(g^{-1}r(X))~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (4)
 $$
 The element $g^{-1}r(X)$, generally, belongs to a different coset
 $$
 g^{-1}r(X)K=g^{-1}X,
 $$
 which has some $r(g^{-1}X)$ as its representative. This enables us to write:
 $$
 g^{-1}r(X) = r(g^{-1}X)~k(X,\,g^{-1})\quad,\quad k(X,\,g^{-1}) \in K~.
 $$
 Then, expression (4) may be extended as
 $$
 U_g \varphi(r(X)) = \varphi(g^{-1}r(X)) = \varphi(~r(g^{-1}X)~ k(X,\,g^{-1})~)~.
 $$
 Had it not been for the subsidiary condition (2), we would have to stop here. However, condition (2) enables us to make one more step:
 $$
 U_g \varphi(r(X)) = D^{-1}(  k(X,\,g^{-1}) )~\varphi( r( g^{-1} X) ) ~.\qquad\qquad\qquad (5)
 $$

Now switch from the Mackey functions defined on $G$ to the *Wigner functions* defined on cosets:
 $$
 \psi(X)\equiv\varphi(r(X))~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (6)
 $$
 In terms of these functions, equation (5) acquires the form of
 $$
 \tilde{U}_g\psi(X) = \tilde{D}^{-1}(  k(X,\,g^{-1}) ) ~\psi(g^{-1}X)~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (7)
 $$
 where $\tilde{U}_g\psi(X)\equiv U_g\varphi(r(X))$ and $\tilde{D}(k)\psi(X) \equiv D(k)\varphi(r(X))$. So equation (7) renders us a transformation law of the Wigner functions.

This way, by switching from the initial representation space ${\mathbb{W}}$ to the space ${\mathbb{V}}$ of Mackey functions (2),
 we have enabled ourselves to construct a representation of $G$ acting on the quotient space $G/K$. The factor $\tilde{D}^{-1}(  k(X,\,g^{-1}) )$ emerging in this representation is known as the *Wigner rotation* and is responsible for a wonderful (and measurable) quantum-mechanical effect known as the *Thomas precession*.

À PROPOS

The group $G$ can be considered as a fibre bundle over the quotient space. By appointing a representative $r(X)$ for each coset $X$,
 we define a section $\sigma(X)$.
  Then the Wigner functions acting on the quotient space can be shortly written as
 $$\psi = \varphi\circ\sigma .$$
 In this notation, $\tilde{U}_g\psi \equiv U_g [\varphi \circ\sigma] $. So the transformation law can be also written down as
 $$
 U_g [\varphi\circ\sigma] (X) = D^{-1}(k(X,g^{-1}))~[\varphi\circ\sigma](g^{-1}X).
 $$

NOW, MY QUESTION

Above we agreed to work in the subspace of the Mackey functions satisfying
 $
 \varphi(gk) = D^{-1}(k)~\varphi(g).
 $
 Specifically, for $g=k^{\,\prime\prime}\in K$, this implies:
 $$
 \varphi(k^{\,\prime\prime} k^{-1}) = D(k)~\varphi(k^{\,\prime\prime})~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (8)
 $$

At the same time, the representation $D(K)$ must agree with the natural representation (3) of the bigger group $G$. Stated differently, we expect that the induced representation $U:~~ G\to{\rm{GL}}({\mathbb{V}})$ becomes $D$ when restricted to $K<G$:
 $$
 U_k\varphi(k^{\,\prime})=\varphi(k^{-1}\,k^{\,\prime}) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (9)
 $$

Setting $k^{\,\prime\prime} = k^{-1}\,k^{\,\prime} k $ in (8) and combining the result with (9), we obtain:
  $$
 U_k\varphi(k^{\,\prime})=\varphi(k^{-1}\,k^{\,\prime}) = \varphi(k^{-1}\,k^{\,\prime} k k^{-1}) = D(k) \varphi (k^{-1}\,k^{\,\prime} k )~.
 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (10)
 $$

Restriction from $G$ to $K$ makes the induced representation $U$ reduce back to $D$, when $K$ is Abelian. Indeed, for $\varphi(k^{-1}~k^{\,\prime} k) = \varphi(k^{\,\prime})$, equation  (10) becomes $U_k\varphi(k^{\,\prime})=D(k)\varphi(k^{\,\prime})~$.

This said, $K$ being Abelian is a sufficient but not necessary condition for
 $$
 \varphi(k^{-1}\,k^{\,\prime} k) = \varphi(k^{\,\prime})~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (11)
 $$
 Even for a non-Abelian $K$, equality (11) is satisfied by spherical functions. This way, if the restriction of the induced representation from $G$ back to $K$ can be expanded into irreducibles each of which has spherical functions as its basis, then the restriction of $\,\mbox{Ind}^{\,G}_{K}D\;$ down to $\,K\;$ renders $\,D(K)\,$:
 $$
 \iota~:\quad K~\hookrightarrow~G~,\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\iota^*~:\quad\mbox{Ind}^{\,G}_{K}D\;{\longrightarrow}~D(K)\qquad\qquad\qquad (12)
 $$
 Does this imply that an induced representation can be implemented on spherical functions only?

Comment: Why do you expect the induced representation to become the original one when restricted? Induction is an adjoint of restriction, not an inverse (and in this language, the induced representation here would often be called co-induced, though we often still just call it induced when we don't care about the usually much too large actually induced one).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you for this valuable comment! You are right. There exists a theorem
$$
\left(~D(K)\uparrow G~\right)\downarrow K~=~\int_{K\backslash G/K}du\;D_u(K)~~,
$$
where the summation is performed over the representatives $u$ of all distinct double cosets $K\backslash G/K$. Unless $G$ happens to be the little group of $K$, we should not expect all $D_u$ to be equivalent to $D$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  Could you also please clarify the difference between the coinduced and induced reps? Do you mean that induced is 
$$
V_g f(y) = f(yg)~~~,\quad  f(ky) = D(k) f(y)  ~~,
$$
while the coinduced is
$$
U_g\varphi(x) = \varphi(g^{-1} x)~~~,\quad \varphi(xk) = D(k^{-1}) \varphi(x)~~,
$$
correct?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I would also be much in your debt if you could recommend me some simple introductory reading on induced reps, available to a layman physicist. Physicists know a bit of groups and algebras, but know nothing of cathegories, ideals, functors -- so some really very simple intro would be of help.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how the induced would look in this case, as I am mainly familiar with the case for algebraic groups, where the induced representation only exists when moving outside the algebraic representations, so I would assume similarly here that in order to get the proper induced representation (i.e. the left adjoint of restriction, rather than the right adjoint as this is), one would need to move outside the smooth representations.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any good introductory text on this (especially the Lie group/smooth representations case, which I know hardly anything about myself).

Comment: You have given me much food for thought. I do appreciate your help!

Comment: You might get good recommendations if you ask a separate question about good books on the topic. The more specifically you state your background and needs, the more precise recommendations people might be able to give. Alternatively, you can drop by the main chat room, which might have someone who knows the subject.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft This is a good idea. I will post such a question. 

And what is the main chat room? How to get there? Oh, I see it now. 
thank you!

Comment: If you click the thing in the top right to get a list of all stackexchange sites, it has a link to chat next to the link to this site (between help and log out). The main room is the one just called "Mathematics"

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Got it. Thank you!